# javascript array value is changing after it has been pushed

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to debug the code below.

It is supposed to create a 2d-array, with all of the permutations of the input string.

It starts off great, and the initial string is pushed to the array, but after I run the reverse function in step 4, the value in strArr changes from having a length of 3 to a length of 2. basically like it is skipping the concat in the reverse function, but when I ran it in the debugger, z has a length of 3 after the concat, but then when the function returns it, the length becomes 2 again.

any help would be appreciated.

```
function permAlone(str) {
  var perms = [];
  var totalPerms = factorial(str.length);
  var strCodes = converter(str);
  var strArr = [];
  strArr.push(strCodes);
  // overall loop
  for (var X = 0; X < totalPerms; X++) {

    //step 1
    var largestI = -1;
    for (var i = 0; i < strCodes.length - 1; i++) {
      if (strCodes[i] < strCodes[i + 1]) {
        largestI = i;
      }
    }
    //if none found break loop
    if (largestI == -1) {
      break;
    }

    //step 2
    var largestJ = -1;
    for (var j = 0; j < strCodes.length; j++) {
      if (strCodes[largestI] < strCodes[j]) {
        largestJ = j;
      }
    }

    //step 3
    swap(strCodes, largestI, largestJ);

    //step 4
    strCodes = reverse(strCodes, largestI);

    //step 5 push to array
    strArr.push(strCodes);
  }
  console.log(strArr);
  return strArr;
}

function factorial(x) {
  for (var i = x - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    x *= i;
  }
  return x;
}

function converter(x) {
  var temp = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    temp.push(x.charCodeAt(i));
  }
  return temp;
}

function swap(a, i, j) {
  var temp = a[i];
  a[i] = a[j];
  a[j] = temp;
}

function reverse(z, a) {
  var endArr = z.splice(a+1);
  endArr.reverse();
  z = z.concat(endArr);
  return z;
}

debugger;
permAlone('abc');
```

Comment: I have a feeling this has something to do with shallow and deep copies of the variable. I am running some tests now, if I figure it out I will post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The reverse function returns a new array and does not manipulate the existing. You need to change your code to the following:

```
endArr = endArr.reverse();
```

Comment: I tried this, and still have the same issue.

the mdn reference also says the reverse function mutates the array in place, so I thought that ment it was affecting the actual array and updatting it without setting the variable again. maybe I need to brush up on muttating as well :)

Comment: reverse does mutate the existing array - when in doubt [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)

Comment: You have it backward. The `reverse` function does **not** return a new array and **does** manipulate the existing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it was an issue with having a shallow copy of the array.

I added   z = z.slice(); to the reverse function and it fixed the issue.